# Unable to start tomcat server after commenting "spring-boot-starter-security" in pom.xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Unable to start tomcat server after commenting "spring-boot-starter-security" in pom.xml file = Using Spring Version 2.4.1

Commented below in pom.xml file.

spring-boot-starter-security

Entire POM.xml file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebApp</name>
    <description>WebApp Java</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When Tomcat is reloaded below error is seen

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'thymeleafViewResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafWebMvcConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'thymeleafViewResolver' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEngine' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine]: Factory method 'templateEngine' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafSecurityDialectConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@11028347]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:617) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
```

Comment: Can you pelase check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270322/spring-boot-security-thymeleaf-iprocessordialect-class-missing

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @silentsudo
It Worked!! The link which you shared really helped.
I updated the POM.xml file as below and it worked!! Thanks Again for you help!!

FROM
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>

TO
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>